# How to update default-style per jQuery in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to dynamically update the CSS-Stylesheet of my page using jQuery and everything seems to be working fine in Chrome, but sadly in IE11 doesnt seems to do the trick.

The following code shows the HTML and JS Files:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="default-style" content="style-02">
    <title>Stylesheet Switcher</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-01.css" title="style-01">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-02.css" title="style-02">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-03.css" title="style-03">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    Change style
    <select id="styleChanger">
        <option value="style-01">style-01</option>
        <option value="style-02">style-02</option>
        <option value="style-03">style-03</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <img src="icons.gif" alt="Smiley face">
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var theme = localStorage.getItem('style');
    if (!theme) {
        localStorage.setItem('style', 'style-01');
    };

    updateTheme();

    $("#styleChanger").val(theme);

    $("#styleChanger").change(function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem('style', selectedValue);
        updateTheme();
    });
});

function updateTheme()
{
    currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('style');
    $('meta[http-equiv=default-style]')[0].content = currentTheme;
};
```

Does anybody knows, why after updating the "content" in the META tag IE doesnt loads the new CSS File?

Thanks for your help

Comment: how did you try to debug?

Comment: using the standard IE console. There I can see that the original META in the HTML is correctly updated, but the styles are not reloaded by IE (opposite as in Chrome or Firefox) <meta http-equiv="default-style" content="style-02">